# 2 SQL queries at once

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I concatenate these two queries, so that I can have 3 columns in my result: postcode, memberCount and placeCount

```
SELECT LEFT(`delivery_postcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`delivery_postcode`) as `count`
FROM `customer_cards`
WHERE `delivery_postcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `delivery_postcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

and

```
SELECT LEFT(`placePostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`placePostcode`) as `placeCount`
FROM `RestaurantsForGoogleMaps`
WHERE `placePostcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `placePostcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `placeCount` DESC
```

At the moment my results look like the following, for either query

```
postcode | count/placeCount
------------------------
SW       | 817
W1       | 533
EC       | 395
```

Comment: Create each select as an inline view and then join on postcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT LEFT(`delivery_postcode`, 2) as `postcode`
,     count(`delivery_postcode`) as `count`
,     pc.placeCount
FROM `customer_cards` cc
LEFT JOIN  (
               SELECT LEFT(`placePostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, 
               count(`placePostcode`) as `placeCount`
               FROM `RestaurantsForGoogleMaps`
               WHERE `placePostcode` IS NOT NULL
                   AND `placePostcode` <> ''
              GROUP BY `postcode`
           ) pc
       on  pc.postcode = LEFT(cc.delivery_postcode, 2)
WHERE `delivery_postcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `delivery_postcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Comment: First try lumped 90% of them into a '0' postcode, but the revision works great :) takes about 9 seconds through 11 million rows, so not too bad. I will mark the fastest query as the answer, because I'm not exactly an SQL expert I don't know which answer is 'best'

Comment: Yeah, I imagined it needed some refinement. Glad it worked for you. Which is "best" depends on what you consider "good", speed is a good enough indicator :P

Comment: I think I was just too eager, I had tried it within a few seconds of it being posted :) Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT postcode,count,placecount FROM (SELECT LEFT(`delivery_postcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`delivery_postcode`) as `count`, 0 as `placecount`
    FROM `customer_cards`
    WHERE `delivery_postcode` IS NOT NULL
    AND `delivery_postcode` <> ''
    GROUP BY `postcode`
    UNION
SELECT LEFT(`placePostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`placePostcode`) as `placecount`,0 as `count`
    FROM `RestaurantsForGoogleMaps`
    WHERE `placePostcode` IS NOT NULL
    AND `placePostcode` <> ''
    GROUP BY `postcode` )  ORDER BY count desc
```

Comment: After aliasing the UNION this worked, but it is grouping my two counts together - I want the two counts seperate next to each postcode. I've tried changing one of the count aliases but they still get grouped

Comment: Thanks mate, still not on the mark though unfortunately. placecount is returning 0 on all rows - I'm not sure if the values have been added or what though. I have a solution though, so don't feel the need to fix it for my sake :)

Comment: This one does seem faster though, even though the results aren't right, it's finishing in only 3 sec as opposed to 9

Answer (score 0):

Create both queries as an inline views and then join on postcode.  This assumes both queries return the desired results and that POST CODE is the key on which to join and there are no other attributes needing to complete the join properly.  It also assumes the post code would be in both tables.

If not, then we have to replicate the join as right and left and union the results together.

```
SELECT A.postcode, A.mcount, B.placecount
FROM
  (SELECT LEFT(delivery_postcode, 2) as postcode, count(delivery_postcode) as mcount
  FROM customer_cards
  WHERE delivery_postcode IS NOT NULL
  AND delivery_postcode <> ''
  GROUP BY LEFT(delivery_postcode, 2)) A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LEFT(placePostcode, 2) as postcode, count(placePostcode) as placeCount
  FROM RestaurantsForGoogleMaps
  WHERE placePostcode IS NOT NULL
  AND placePostcode <> ''
  GROUP BY LEFT(placePostcode, 2)) B
on A.postcode = B.postcode
order by A.postcode
```

Comment: `Unknown column 'a.postcode' in 'field list'` on this one - It doesn't seem to recognise delivery_postcode, placePostcode or postcode though, as a. or b. columns

Comment: I updated a few components but I can't imagine why this wasn't working before if each select operates on its own.

Comment: Perhaps case sensitivity is an issue.  I ensured all are pper case.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment my results look like the following, for either query

```
;WITH PC1 AS (
SELECT LEFT(`delivery_postcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`delivery_postcode`) as `count`
FROM `customer_cards`
WHERE `delivery_postcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `delivery_postcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `count` DESC

),
PC2 AS (

SELECT LEFT(`placePostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`placePostcode`) as `placeCount`
FROM `RestaurantsForGoogleMaps`
WHERE `placePostcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `placePostcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `placeCount` DESC

)

SELECT a.postcode, a.count,b.placeCount
FROM PC1 a
LEFT JOIN PC2 b
ON a.postcode = b.postcode
```